# ui_component image upload field in form

Tags: magento2, image, uicomponent

I've created **ui_form**

Form in working fine, Image also render when i edit form.

But when i am trying to update image it giving me below prompt.

[image]

This is what I've in my ui_form for Image.

```
<field name="profile">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">contact</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Group Image</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/image-preview</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="credit/grid/upload"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

I also created preview file.

```
<div class="file-uploader-summary">
<div class="file-uploader-preview">
    <a attr="href: $parent.getFilePreview($file)" target="_blank">
        <img
            class="preview-image"
            tabindex="0"
            event="load: $parent.onPreviewLoad.bind($parent)"
            attr="
                src: $parent.getFilePreview($file),
                alt: $file.name">
    </a>

    <div class="actions">
        <button
            type="button"
            class="action-remove"
            data-role="delete-button"
            attr="title: $t('Delete image')"
            click="$parent.removeFile.bind($parent, $file)">
            <span translate="'Delete image'"/>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="file-uploader-filename" text="$file.name"/>
<div class="file-uploader-meta">
    <text args="$file.previewWidth"/>x<text args="$file.previewHeight"/>
</div>
```

Below is the controller for upload.

```
public function execute()
{
    try {
        $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('contact');

        $result['cookie'] = [
            'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
            'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
            'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
            'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
            'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
        ];
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->critical($e);
        $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
    }
    return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);

}
```

**I can't figure out what's issue,
If i dump `$_FILES` at controller its showing data.
Anyone has idea what's missing in this ??
Thanks in Advance.**